# How to use picture element as background image?

Tags: 8, media, theming

With the simple image field we are able to set the image style and use that to set the image as a background for a div tag (see example below). HOwever, as Drupal 8 has [Responsive Image](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/mobile-guide/responsive-images-in-drupal-8) module, the image field will generate like below. With different breakpoints, different images are fetched by the browser, but this make it difficult to set the image as a background.

The current implementation is flexible because as the text grows so does the height of the div containing the image as a background image.

How would you use the picture tag to set the image as a background? I have not found a way to have Drupal detect what image is being fetched by the browser.

Goal:

1. Have image as a background
2. Overlay text on top of image
3. As the overlay text grows, so does the div containing the text. As such the image as a background should grow as well.

Current implementation without Responsive Images:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper_img" style="background-image: url('/sites/default/files/banner_large/name.jpg')"></div>
    <div class="wrapper_content">Authoritatively reinvent magnetic ROI without excellent interfaces. Professionally drive extensive manufactured products through 24/365 leadership. </div>
</div>
```

Responsive image outputs which makes it difficult to set the background image (banner_large, banner_medium, banner_small are image styles)

```
<picture>
<source srcset="/sites/default/files/banner_large/name.jpg 1x" media="all and (min-width:1200px) type="image/png" >
<source srcset="/sites/default/files/banner_medium/name.jpg 1x" media="all and (min-width:768px) type="image/png" >
<source srcset="/sites/default/files/banner_small/name.jpg 1x" media="all and (min-width:320px) type="image/png" >

<img src="/sites/default/files/banner_small/name.jpg" alt="text" typeof="foaf:Image">

</picture>
```

Comment: You could just use CSS, use the `z-index` to move the text in front of the of the image. See [example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex).

Comment: @NoSssweat the problem with that is i need the div.wrapper to grow as the div.wrapper_content grows. If the text gets larger or smaller than the image should also get grow/shrink with it, hence the div.wrapper element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that we can modify the [responsive-image.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21responsive_image%21templates%21responsive-image.html.twig/8.2.x) to do what we need. We used a combination of the following links:

1. [Responsive images](https://responsiveimages.org/)
2. [Responsive images (MDN Web docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)